# Rename webstore products directory and redirect all its contents

Tags: apache

I want to rename our webstore products directory, and redirect all its contents, from /products/ to /Product/ using htaccess.

The problem is that we have several individual domain names (mysite.com, mysite.co.uk) accessing this directory so the resultant htaccess code cannot specify a single destination domain such as .com

Answer (score 0):

As long as all domains/vhosts use the same namespace, you can use the same RewriteRule in all vhosts/.htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/\.]+.*) /Product/$1 [L]
```

Good luck!
Alex.

Comment: Thanks Alex but that doesn't seem to do anything at all.